# add dynamic id to links using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many links on a page generated dynamically. Now I want to attach ids to them based on a link just before them.

I have written the following function to return me the value I want to add as id to the href I want.

```
<script>
function movingid(){
    var res = location.href.replace(/.*student\/(.*)\/subject/, '$1');
    var subjectid = res.split("/")[2];
    var classid = res.split("/")[1];
    var sectionid = res.split("/")[0];
    return classid+"-"+sectionid+"-"+subjectid;
    }
</script>
```

So  what I did is

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id= "javascript:movingid();" >Move To</a>
```

But the HTML thus generated is not calling the function. Instead its adding the id as plain text form like this `id= "javascript:movingid();"`. How can I call the function?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the links this way:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id= "" >Move To</a>
```

Maybe wrapping the links with a div, which gets the id "mylinks". After this call a function adding the id with this code:

```
i = "1";
$( "div#mylinks a" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).attr("id",i);
  i++;
});
```

Instead of **i** take your code from the movingid function you already posted.